# Is it possible to move a Git branch right to the last rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, git-reset

I just rebased a Git branch called `chattisekoilua` onto the `master` branch of my project, did something stupid on `chattisekoilua` (as in deleted some files I shouldn't have) and would like to set the state of the `chattisekoilua` branch to the moment right after the rebase.

How could I accomplish this? I've not made any commits after the rebase, if that's relevant.

Comment: On which branch did you make the mistake?

Comment: The one that's not `master`, called `chattisekoilua` from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy - just do:

```
git reset --hard
```

Warning: this discards any uncommitted changes without asking for confirmation!

Comment: I'm assuming this sets the state of the branch to the last commit.

Comment: @TheSodesa Yes, that's right. But the state of the branch is already correct - it's just the working tree (and possibly the index) that will be changed.